# c# compiler version not compatible

Tags: angular, npm

I am trying to create a project using ng new command. I am encountering this issue. I am not able to figure out why c# version should be a problem while trying to create a new angular project

```
     ng new my-dream-app

    ? Would you like to add Angular routing? No
    ? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
    CREATE my-dream-app/angular.json (3822 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/package.json (1319 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/README.md (1027 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/tsconfig.json (408 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/tslint.json (2837 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/.editorconfig (246 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/.gitignore (503 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/src/favicon.ico (5430 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/src/index.html (297 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/src/polyfills.ts (3234 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/src/test.ts (642 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/src/browserslist (388 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/src/karma.conf.js (964 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/src/tsconfig.app.json (166 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/src/tsconfig.spec.json (256 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/src/tslint.json (314 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/src/environments/environment.ts (662 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/src/app/app.module.ts (314 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/src/app/app.component.html (1141 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (996 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/src/app/app.component.ts (216 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/e2e/protractor.conf.js (752 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json (213 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (304 bytes)
    CREATE my-dream-app/e2e/src/app.po.ts (204 bytes)
    Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.7.3056.0
    for C# 5
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240

    fatal error CS2006: Command-line syntax error: Missing ':<text>' for '/d' option
    Package install failed, see above.
```

---

```
    **NODE version - 8.11.3**
    **npm version - 6.11.3**
    **ng version - 7.0.7**
```

---

Comment: Your C# compiler is outdated, you need to install new version, as it is clearly mentioned in the error itself "This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5 which is no longer the latest version"

Comment: But why i am getting that while installing angular. Is angular dependent on c#?

Comment: You are using visual studio right?

Comment: No I am not using visual studio. I am installing from cmd directly.

Comment: C# errors for Angular CLI ? Try to ```npm uninstall -g @angular/cli ``` , ```npm cache clean --force``` and ```npm i -g @angular/cli@7.x```

Comment: Finally figured it out, turns out somehow the ComSpec environment variable path got set to C# compilers path. Everything started to work fine after I set it back to cmd path.